# My Device Keeps Rebooting (LogCat attached)

Tags: logging, battery, reboot

For some reason, after I changed my device's battery. It just keeps rebooting and here's a LogCat of the error:

```
E/JavaBinder( 1305): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=6  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateAllPhoneStateLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:1907)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:1937)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.notePhoneSignalStrength(BatteryStatsService.java:211)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastSignalStrengthChanged(TelephonyRegistry.java:564)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifySignalStrength(TelephonyRegistry.java:325)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact(ITelephonyRegistry.java:95)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)  
E/JavaBinder( 1305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you downloaded any performance app recently?

Comment: No, I used to use the one in CM7 but I changed the ROM and now I don't use anything. Although this problem did also exist in CM7.

Comment: Kill your batterstatsservice from running services. There is something wrong with it.

Comment: It seems the battery you recently installed is not supportive for the device.

Comment: Might this be the problem? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nema.batterycalibration&hl=en

Comment: But I used this battery before and it worked perfectly, till recently. And this problem also persists when I use the battery that shipped with my device.

Comment: And also when I boot without my SD card, this problem seems to go

Comment: I uninstalled the app and switched to the battery that shipped with my device, and i'm still getting reboots.

Comment: that is all that is in the logcat? how are you getting the logcat, it clears when the device reboots. There could be something else causing the crash but you never get to see the logcat for it. Did you wipe your data before changing ROMs?

Comment: No that's not all the logcat, that's the critical part. I got this logcat from aLogCat and saved it right before the device rebooted. If you want to see the full logcat, it's right here: http://pastebin.com/v0dsEuRQ

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything in the full logcat is an error. I would suggest going a full wipe of Data & Cache and then reinstall your custom ROM. There is no way to know for sure that the part you posted in the original question is the one causing the reboot. They system rebooting may not allow the actual app that is causing it to write to the logcat.

You are hiving errors in everything from Telephony to the Installer. It sounds like there is something in the system that is causing a problem, See if clearing the Data and Cache fixes it, especially if you never cleared it before switching from one ROM to another.

---

Based on your comment that you have tried clearing the cache and data, i would suggest then to try and clear the battery stats. This can be done in Clockwork Recovery, I think there are apps in the market that can do it too, but I dont know if you can get to those as your device is rebooting all the time.

If that doesn't solve it, I would try a different battery because if you have cleared the cache and data and also tried multiple ROMs and still have the same problem, then it sounds like faulty hardware.

Comment: Always clear my cache and data, tried numurous ROMs and still, no result.

Comment: if you have tried multiple roms, and cleared cache and data on them all, you may have faulty hardware. one other suggestion, try clearing the battery stats. If that doesn't do any thing, then try a different battery.

Comment: Tried clearing battery stats and tried the battery that shipped with my device. The problem goes when I use the other battery, but if I reboot the device, then the problem comes back. Also, I noticed that if I boot without the SD card, the problem goes away completely.

Comment: do you have any apps installed to the sdcard?

Comment: Yes, I do have apps on my sd card.

Comment: I suggest removing the apps from the SDcard, or moving them back to the device and see if that solve the problem. One of the apps may not run well while on the sdcard.

Comment: I have about 300 and something apps, and only 1 gig of Internal Memory :s. Isn't there a way to know which app this is?